# How to calculate an overall 5 star rating based on other weighted 5 star ratings

Tags: arithmetic, average

I have these 3 ratings.  I want to combine them to produce an overall rating out of 5.  The overall rating can be a float, so no rounding is necessary, but it cannot be negative.  I'm just not sure how to do it.

Technical Rating from 1 to 5, weighting 2:1  (i.e A rating of 5 equals 10)

Production Rating from 1 to 5, weighting 1:1

Content Rating from 1 to 5, weighting 3:1

Any hints or advice would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Good clear description of your question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks!  Sadly, I've had a lot of practice asking questions! ;)

Comment: If you need something more elaborate try some fuzzy inference mechanism (fuzzification/defuzzification). Every rating values induces a fuzzy set accompanied by a membership function. But, I think the answer by Henry should be sufficient for most applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like $$\frac{2TR + PR + 3CR}{6}.$$

Try it with various examples including

- $(5,5,5)$ to give a result of $5$,
- $(1,1,1)$ to give a result of $1$,
- $(4,1,1)$ to give a result of $2$,
- $(1,4,1)$ to give a result of $1.5$,
- $(1,1,4)$ to give a result of $2.5$,

to see the effect.

Comment: I have a smallish brain, so I really don't get how this works, but it does.  Thank you!!

Comment: It is called a weighted average and uses your weights.  Note that $2+1+3 = 6$.